# Can not override a method from super class

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to override two methods of a class named DKImagePickerControllerDefaultUIDelegate.

I was able to override the following method.

```
func layoutForImagePickerController(_ imagePickerController: DKImagePickerController) -> UICollectionViewLayout.Type
```

But I am unable to override this one.

```
func imagePickerController(_ imagePickerController: DKImagePickerController, didSelectAssets: [DKAsset])
```

[DKImagePickerControllerDefaultUIDelegate](https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController/blob/master/DKImagePickerController/DKImagePickerControllerDefaultUIDelegate.swift) is the link of class I was trying to subclass.

[image: Here are the methods I want to override.]

Here is the issue I am getting when I tried to override the method.

[image: Issue I am getting when I tried to override.]

Comment: But your class seem to have no superclass at all. What do you expect to override? Protocols are not classes.

Comment: when i go to definition, it has following signature:
open class DKImagePickerControllerDefaultUIDelegate: NSObject, DKImagePickerControllerUIDelegate {

Comment: I am able to override first method but can not override another one.

Comment: try alt + cttrl + shift + k (clean build folder)

Comment: cleaning build folder does not work for it.

Answer (score 0):

You class doesn't have super class. So override method will not work. I tried your given library and it will not work as per your given way. For basic understanding i have created same mimic structure here for you to easily understand.

```
protocol ATDelegate {
func handleUIChange() -> String
func didSelectAssets()
}

class ATCustomUIDelegate:ATDelegate{


func handleUIChange() -> String {
    return ""
}

func didSelectAssets() {

}
}

class ATOverrideCustomUIDelegate:ATCustomUIDelegate{

override func didSelectAssets() {

}
}
```

Above same case will applies with DKImagePickerControllerUIDelegate.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. This is the similar mimic structure. Can you please tell me why I can override first method and can not the second one?